# Drop Down List Form Submission

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to submit the Form when select a option from the dropdown list. But It's not working. can any one please help me to fix this issue. I have attached My Code Below.

Thanks in Advance,

```
<div class="main" id="main">
  <h2>Sell / Rent Advertisments</h2>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form.php">
  <table width="531" height="121" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="81"><div>
        <label>I wish to:</label>
      </div></td>
      <td width="76">
        <label for="mediaId"></label>
        <select name="mediaId" id="mediaId">


          <option selected value="Sale">Sale</option>
          <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td width="360"><label for="type"></label>
        <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="_Any" selected="selected">- - Not Specified - -</option>
<option value="1" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">Apartment</option>
<option value="3" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">Building</option>
<option value="4" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">Hotels/Guest Houses</option>
<option value="5" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">House</option>
<option value="6" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">Land</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You got your `onchange` on `option`s. It should be on `select`

Comment: Faris, I understand removing `ajax` tag, but why would you want to remove `jQuery` tag? Maybe the OP is looking for a possible solution in jQuery too?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `onClick` instead of `onChange` like

```
<option value="1" onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit()">Apartment</option>
```

Comment: -1, on click fires the moment a user tries to open the dropdown, not after an option has been selected

Comment: @FarisM the user used onChange in every line. I've suggested use onClick on every line. Try it and then vote or comment

Comment: I don't know why, but I'd never use this approach. This just feels... wrong

Comment: programming is fired by logic,imagination not by emotion

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<select name="type" id="type"  onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">
    <option value="_Any" selected="selected">- - Not Specified - -</option>
    <option value="1">Apartment</option>
    <option value="3" >Building</option>
    <option value="4" >Hotels/Guest Houses</option>
    <option value="5" >House</option>
    <option value="6" >Land</option>
    </select>
```

That is, apply `onChange` event to `select` instead of `option`

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form id="form1" ...>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="_Any" selected="selected">- - Not Specified - -</option>
        <option value="1">Apartment</option>
        <option value="3">Building</option>
        <option value="4">Hotels/Guest Houses</option>
        <option value="5">House</option>
        <option value="6">Land</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

No jquery, just javascript

Put the onchange in the `select` tag, not in each individual `option` tags

```
<select name="type" id="type" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">
```

jQuery

Separate functionality from markup, and put this text in `$.ready()`

```
$('#type').change( function(){
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The onChange should be place on the  tag, you 'change' the select's option but not changing anything on the options..

```
<select name="type" id="type" onChange="document.forms['form1'].submit()">
```